# My jQuery UI slider's animation is buggy and it's freezing the whole page occasionally, how is my code wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

*Updated! Again...*

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm learning online but this is the point where I'm stuck.

I was trying to make audio controls for a site (for practice) and since I lack the knowledge to make my own, I decided to use jQuery UI slider. I made a for loop to apply the controls for every future audio element.

The problems are: The slider's handle's left and right border are moving slightly differently when the audio is playing and if I abuse the slider (like moving it fast, left to right) my whole page freezes and requires reload. I'm pretty sure it's my fault, because my code doesn't work at JSFiddle at all.

I uploaded the relevant part of my code here, since JSFiddle couldn't handle the code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3_Wf6a8uWCYN2x6WEgyWGJ3Xzg

The slider is not working here, but I hope someone can find what have I done wrong.

The javascript code of the slider:

```
// sets up the controls for the audios
$("audio").each(function() {

// calls play/pause on click
var currentAudio = $(this)
var currentAudioDom = $(currentAudio).get(0)
var containerId = $(currentAudio).attr("id") + "-container";
$("#" + containerId).click(function() {
  playPause(currentAudioDom)
});

// sets up the slider
var sliderId = $(currentAudio).attr("id") + "-slider";
var audioSlider = $("#" + sliderId);

// slider controls the audio
currentAudioDom.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
  var audioDuration = currentAudio.prop("duration")

  audioSlider.slider({
    max: audioDuration,
    step: 0.1,
    animate: "slow",
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      currentAudioDom.currentTime = ui.value
      if (currentAudioDom.paused === false) {
        currentAudioDom.muted = true;
      }
    },

    stop: function(event, ui) {
      currentAudioDom.muted = false;
    }
  })
});

// audio conrols the slider
$(currentAudio).on("playing", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(audioSlider).slider("option", "value", currentAudioDom.currentTime)
```

Comment: If you go to your jsfiddle, right click on it, select Inspect, and hit the Console tab (this assumes Chrome is the browser), you'll see quite a few errors there.  Some of them have to do with not being able to find the resources you link in.  You also don't have a reference to either jQuery or jQuery-UI, and you need both of those if you want to use the slider.  Perhaps you'll want to start there; getting all your references straightened out.

Comment: Thank you Bob! I managed to fix this problem, now it works on JSFiddle The buggy handle is a problem on JSFiddle too, but it doesn't freeze the page.

Comment: On your fiddle I don't see anything but a picture of a cat with strange glasses.

Comment: I tried my best, but I don't think I can get it working, sometimes it opens the slider sometimes it doesn't. When it's not working, I have to reload and rerun a couple times to see the slider. I think the online mp3 file's metadata doesn't contain the audio's duration, or it loads too slow and the slider can't be initalized before it's loaded. I could avoid getting error for reaching a not initalized object, but it doesn't make the slider appear. (But the image and audio still works, it plays the audio if you click on it)

Comment: I copied the code from JSFiddle into Notepad++, saved the files, and it worked. But the original problem still stands.

Comment: That means it can be viewed by downloading the files trough Google drive. I'd really appreciate an answer, because this should change the way I'll continue my learnings.